# Suppose one glues a Möbius band to the boundary of a disk. What familiar space is this homeomorphic to?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was doing a problem in algebraic topology and I need to gain knowledge of the following fact to procede.  Suppose one glues a Möbius band to the boundary of a disk.  I want to calculate the homologies of this space.  I was wondering if this is homeomorphic to a familiar space, and if so then how would one see it.  My guess was $RP^2$ but I am not sure.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this space is $RP^2$.  An easy way to see it is to start with $RP^2$ in the form of a disk with antipodal boundary points identified, and to remove a small disk that overlaps that boundary.  What remains is easily deformed to a rectangle with two opposite ends identified with a twist, i.e., a Möbius strip.